# DirectX program throw an exception when it is destroyed under window mode

Tags: c++, directx, directx-11

The problem occurs when I try to play with one of the Rastertek DirectX 11 tutorials.

- I changed the `const bool fullscreen value` to `false` so the program runs under window mode
- I changed the window style from `CLIPPINGWINDOW` to `OVERLAPPEDWINDOW`

It works fine except that the program throws an exception when the window is destroyed:

```
Unhandled exception at 0x779715ee in FrustumCulling.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xfeeeff5e.
```

it's tutorial 16 at http://www.rastertek.com/dx11tut16.html

The only modifications I made are:

In **graphicsclass.h**

`const bool FULL_SCREEN = true //false;`

and

```
SystemClass::InitializeWindows
{

...

m_hwnd = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_APPWINDOW, m_applicationName, m_applicationName, 
            WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
            posX, posY, screenWidth, screenHeight, NULL, NULL, m_hinstance, NULL);

...

}
```

Comment: Going to need some more details such as on which tutorial you're on, as in the number of the tutorial from [rastertek](http://rastertek.com/tutdx11.html).

Comment: on which line this error occurs? may be you trying to use released com object (for example in cleanup method)?

Comment: On swapChain->Release(); line this error occurs.

Comment: Does your code literally have "const bool FULL_SCREEN = true //false;" as this won't compile as you've commented out the terminating semicolon unless it then combines with the next line into a valid statement (which would likely break a lot). I consider it much more likely that's not literally what you changed the line to but thought I'd mention it just in case...

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible you're still setting up your swapchain in fullscreen mode?
When I was running into this issue, adding this to my DxClass' destructor solved it

```
if(_swapChain != nullptr)
{
            _swapChain->SetFullscreenState(false, NULL);  
            _swapChain->Release();
            _swapChain = nullptr;
}
```

As per one of the Rastertek comments in one of the tutorials, the swapchain has to have the fullscreen set to false prior to being released.

When you set up your `DXGI_SWAP_CHAIN_DESC` assure you are using `swapChainDesc.Windowed = !FULL_SCREEN` and not a literal bool value, and make sure you set FULL_SCREEN to false, `FULL_SCREEN = true //false;` wouldn't do that and shouldn't compile.